# Как сделать автоматическое растягивание texarea по высоте текста?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Делаю автоматическое растягивание высоты текстового поля под количество строк.

```js
$(".js-comment_field").each(function () {
  this.setAttribute("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px; overflow-y:hidden;");
 }).on("input", function () {
  this.style.height = "auto";
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
 });
```

```css
.field_block {
 margin: 0 0 6px;
 padding: 0 0 1px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 position: relative;
}

.field {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 0 4px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 46px;
 border: none;
 background: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 21px;
 color: #0d0d0d;
 outline: none;
 resize: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

.field_block .line {
 width: 0%;
 height: 2px;
 background: #000;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
}

.field:focus + .line {
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_block">
    <textarea class="field js-comment_field" name="comment" placeholder="Оставьте комментарий"></textarea>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Сейчас тут поле по высоте занимает сразу 2 строки. Как можно сделать, чтобы бала только одна строка, и вторая появлялась при переносе текста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function mobileTextarea(){
 var elem = document.getElementById('textarea'); // здесь textarea - это идентификатор поля, которое будет растягиваться.
 var minRows = 3; // высота поля textarea

 if (elem) {
  // функция расчета строк
  function setRows() {
   elem.rows = minRows; // минимальное количество строк
   // цикл проверки вместимости контента
   do {
    if (elem.clientHeight != elem.scrollHeight) elem.rows += 1;
   } while (elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight);
  }
  setRows();
  elem.rows = minRows;

  // пересчет строк в зависимости от набранного контента
  elem.onkeyup = function(){
   setRows();
  }
 }
}
// навешиваем обработчики посе загрузки окна
if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", mobileTextarea, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", mobileTextarea);
```

```html
    <textarea class="field js-comment_field" id="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Оставьте комментарий"></textarea>
```

Comment: Работает надежнее, если заменить `keyup` на `input` ( + полоска скролла не мигает - хотя она и так скрыта CSS )